# React and Flask-Restful - how to render Jinja template

Tags: reactjs, axios, jinja2, flask-restful

I am building a RESTful Flask API with React at the frontend.

I want to be able to use React to get and upload data, but render my Jinja templates first at server side with Flask. This is what I have so far:

---

*React*

**Seeds.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Seeds extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      restaurant:'',      
      email: '',
      id: '',
      username: '',
      active: '',
      admin: ''    
    };
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getSeeds();
    }
  };
  getSeeds(event) {
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/seeds`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)  
      console.log(res.data.data) 
      this.setState({
        restaurant: res.data.data[0].restaurant,
        template: res.data.data[0].content
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };

    render(){
        let seeds_page;
        seeds_page = this.setState.template;

        return (
           <div className="form">
            {seeds_page}
           </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Seeds;
```

---

*Flask*

**seeds.py**

```
seeds_bp = Blueprint('seeds', 
                     __name__, 
                     template_folder='templates', 
                     static_url_path='static') 

@seeds_bp.route('/seeds', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def seeds():

    user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()

    response_object = {
          'status': 'success',
          'message': 'success',
          'data': [{"user": user.restaurant,
                    "content": "seeds.html"}]
    }        
    return jsonify(response_object), 200
```

---

*Jinja*

**seeds.html**

```
{% include 'partials/head.html' %}
<section id="woz-content" >

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title">Menu(edit)</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <h2 class="page-title">Seeds</h2>

    <ul style="list-style:none" >
        <li><form action="{{ url_for('seeds.handle_seeds') }}"method="post">Seed1
            <input type="text" name="seed1"/>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;"></label>  
            <input type="submit" value="seed" >
          </form>
        </li>
       <li><form action="{{ url_for('seeds.handle_seeds') }}" method="post">Seed2
            <input type="text" name="seed2"/>
            <label style="font-size: 11px;"></label>
            <input type="submit" value="seed" >
          </form></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

I manage to get my data, but no rendering is carried on.

How can I tweak the code in order to render my template while getting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to render seeds.html inside react component because you have this code inside react component:

```
render(){
        let seeds_page;
        seeds_page = this.setState.template;

        return (
           <div className="form">
            {seeds_page}
           </div>
        );
    }
```

To achieve this action, you need to assure that your seeds.html file have the same syntax of JSX. For example, this code did not work inside your react component:

```
<h1 class='title'>Some title</h1>
```

because react use className instead of class. So, you need to rewrite your seeds.html to be similar to JSX Syntax or find react module can parse html template to JSX code. It will be similar to this:

```
{% include 'partials/head.html' %}
<section id="woz-content" >

  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="page-title">Menu(edit)</h1>
  </div>
  ...
</section>
```

Then you can render the template using render_template function:

```
from flask import render_template
@seeds_bp.route('/seeds', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def seeds():

    user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    example = "some example"
    template = render_template('seeds.html', example=example)

    response_object = {
          'status': 'success',
          'message': 'success',
          'data': [{"user": user.restaurant,
                    "content": template}]
    }        
    return jsonify(response_object)
```

Then, you can get the template via axios request and saved in the template state. To convert the template string to react component, you can use [React HTML Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser) an utility for converting HTML strings into React components.
So Seeds.jsx will be similar to this:

```
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 }
from 'react-html-parser';

class Seeds extends Component{
    constructor (props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            restaurant:'',      
            email: '',
            id: '',
            username: '',
            active: '',
            admin: '',
            template: ''    
         };
    };
    // ... 
    render(){
        var seeds_page = this.state.template;

        return (
           <div className="form">
            { ReactHtmlParser(seeds_page) }
           </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Seeds;
```

Comment: this is what i get after applying your solution: Line 47:  ` 'seeds_page' is not defined  no-undef` and `  Line 51:  'seeds_page' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: did you initialate template like this: constructor(props){ this.state = { template: ""}...}?

Comment: no...could you pease edit your answer adding this to my constructor above?

Comment: it works now, but Rect does not allow the declaration `seeds_page = this.state.template`, after `render()` and before `return`. In order to work, I must do this, inside `return`: `{ ReactHtmlParser(this.state.template) }`

Comment: I'm not convinced because i have some code similar to this works for me. The only difference is the var. Please try this: var seeds_page = this.state.template;

Comment: Anytime, glad it helped.